# Что лучше для организации API на NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, дизайн-api

Я хочу создать API на NodeJs. API работает с веб-сокетом. К этому веб-сокету подключаются клиенты и работают как listener. А сервер шлет информацию для клиентов.

Вопрос:

Я хочу использовать модули ratelimiting, validator, ORM. Посоветуйте, какие взять? или какие фрэймворки ?

Comment: Спасибо @Nofate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть отличный универсальный framework - [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/)
Для работы с сокетами - [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Для создания полнофункционального REST API сервера используйте [loopback](http://loopback.io/)
И конечно [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) умеет всё, что вам нужно.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к expressjs + socket.io. Это самые распространенные фрейморки, будет больше всего инфы по ним. В качестве ORM у меня положительные отзывы о Sequelize.

Comment: @diproart   Я хочу использовать веб-соккет, не socket.io

Comment: @Alijon Это базис, с чего начать. для websocket - https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket. Express имеет множество расширений. В ответе точки старта, для понимания идеологии. nodejs развивается очень быстро, однозначно рекомендовать что-то не решусь. Важно понимать принципы, отличия, подходы к разработке на nodejs. "Для этого потребуется время и усердие".

Comment: @diproart  Спасибо за ответ.  Я уже начинал с total.js (mvc). Как думаешь что лучше? total.js или express ?

Comment: @Alijon IMHO это express, и популярность на github просто так не завоюешь. Но express требует больше знаний, связка express и mongoose хорошее начало в nodejs / nosql. Пока в nodejs нет 100% решений, порог вхождения в разработку остается высоким. Но тренд очевиден. Поэтому можно брать любой, главное изучать не только фреймворк, а именно nodejs, mongodb и т.д. / "держать руку на пульсе" )